# OpenGL - getting translation parameters from ModelView Matrix

Tags: c, opengl

I am doing in a simplistic experiment as below:

```
glPushMatrix();
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW, modelMatrix);

glTranslatef(...);
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW, modelMatrix);
glPopMatrix();
```

However, after the translation, there is not change in the modelview matrix. I am wondering why is that, and how can I see the effect of this translation? In other words, how can I get the transformation marix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is invalid. The correct enum for `glGet...()` is `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX`, not `GL_MODELVIEW` (which is a constant for use `glMatrixMode()`), so all you get is some GL error, and the memory at `modelMatrix` will be not touched at all, so it is probably just left uninitialized.

Comment: I totally missed that. That you get from not using the fixed function pipeline for a very looong time :) Good catch!